# List Index Out of Range Error Has Me Beat

Tags: python, django, forms, indexing

This has been getting the better of me for 2 days. I need to restrict the size of my POST data due to poor performance. I get the IndexError 'list index out of range' when I run this. I have a complex group of queries running that get bundled together and the results get assigned to 'qs.' When teh formset factory gets called to add a second form, it uses my 'Transaction' class of objects; problem is, as a whole, that table is huge. I then the the created form and use it with the POST data from the page. When the data is gathered, it seems as if it is querying my entire table. I have attached the entire view, and the problematic form. I appreciate any help I can get.

View:

```
def update_pdate(request):

    STATES = ['Routed','Reconciled']

    formset = None

    form = StudyOnlyForm()

    study_pk = request.GET.get('study', '0')
    if study_pk == '' or study_pk == '0':
        study_pk = 0

    # child transactions that are 'Recoginzed',
    # reportable with a 'Routed' parent
    qs = Transaction.objects.filter(contract__reportable=True,
            cleared = False,
            contract__study__pk=study_pk,
            transaction_status='Recognized',
            parent_transaction__isnull=False,
            parent_transaction__transaction_status__in=STATES)

    #Designed to capture standalone contracts
    qs1 = Transaction.objects.filter(contract__reportable=True,
            cleared = False,
            contract__study__pk=study_pk,
            contract__contract_type__name='Standalone',
            transaction_status__in=STATES)

    #Captures Arms contracts for Milestone payments
    parent_list = []
    arms_list = []

    parent = Transaction.objects.filter(parent_transaction__isnull=True,
        contract__reportable=True,
        cleared = False,
        contract__study__pk=study_pk,
        contract__contract_type__name='ARMs',
        transaction_status__in=STATES)

    children = Transaction.objects.filter(contract__reportable=True,
            cleared = False,
            contract__study__pk=study_pk,
            transaction_status='Recognized',
            contract__contract_type__name='ARMs',
            parent_transaction__isnull=False,
            parent_transaction__transaction_status__in=STATES)

    for child_item in children:
        parent_list.append(child_item.parent_transaction.pk)
        arms_list.append(child_item.pk)

    for parent_item in parent:
        if parent_item.pk not in parent_list:
            arms_list.append(parent_item.pk)

    qs3 = Transaction.objects.filter(pk__in=arms_list)

    qs4 = qs | qs1 | qs3

    qs = qs4.order_by('-pk')

    formset = modelformset_factory(Transaction, form=PaidDateForm, extra=0, can_delete=False)

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = formset(request.POST, queryset = qs)
        if formset.is_valid():
            updated_transactions = formset.save(commit=False)
            for trans in updated_transactions:
                if trans.paid_amount is not None and trans.date_cleared is not None:
                    trans_to_change = Transaction.objects.get(pk=trans.pk)
                    trans_to_change.paid_amount = trans.paid_amount
                    trans_to_change.date_cleared = trans.date_cleared
                    trans_to_change.paid_currency = trans_to_change.entered_currency
                    trans_to_change.paid_amount_usd = Decimal(str(trans_to_change.paid_amount * Decimal(str(trans_to_change.exchange_rate)).quantize(Decimal('0.01')))).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
                    trans_to_change.edited_by = request.user
                    trans_to_change.cleared = True
                    trans_to_change.save()
            if updated_transactions:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'The transactions have been updated successfully.')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('track:update_pdate'))
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'No transactions have been updated.')

                return render_to_response(
                    'track/paid_date_update.html',
                    {'formset':formset,
                     'form': form,
                     'study_pk':study_pk,
                    },
                    context_instance=template.RequestContext(request))

    else:
        formset = formset(queryset=qs)

    return render_to_response(
            'track/paid_date_update.html',
            {'formset':formset,
             'form': form,
             'study_pk':study_pk,
            },
            context_instance=template.RequestContext(request))
```

Form:

```
class PaidDateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    print 'PaidDateForm() begins'
    formfield_callback = jquery_datefield
    print 'end of jquery callback'
    #date_paid = forms.DateField(label="Paid Date", required=False)
    #paid_amount = forms.DecimalField(label="Cleared Amount",max_digits=14,decimal_places=2,required=False)
    date_cleared = forms.DateField(label="Cleared Date",widget=JQueryDateWidget(), input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        include = ('date_time_created')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = Transaction.objects.filter(pk__in=qs)
        super(PaidDateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            if field != 'date_cleared':
                #self.fields[field].queryset = qs
                self.fields[field].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        #self.fields['paid_amount'].widget.attrs['size'] = 12
        #self.initial['paid_amount'] = '%.2f' % (self.instance.usd_amount)
```

Comment: is your `qs` returning an empty queryset ?

Comment: I'm truly not sure the "qs | qs1 | qs3" gives you a valid Transaction queryset at all. Indeed this "|" is is the bitwise operator for union, so I think it returns you all the functions of the queryset, but not a valid queryset. And this could crash the formset() function call. Try to print that qs and check it's a queryset

Comment: It returns a valid set. This has been running, now just trying to make it efficient. Currently trying to figure out how to pass a boolean to my PaidDateForm()'s __init__ via my first instance of the form where formset=formset(queryset=qs)

Answer (score 1):

You should enable debug mode an study the error report. It has the full exception info and traceback pluss much of the data actually present at the time the fault kicked in. I found this info wery helpful.

Comment: The error is with the line that has 'formset = formset(request.POST, queryset = qs).'  That is where the form gets called.

Comment: Now, it is complaining about qs not being globally defined, tied to the line at the bottom of my view:

formset = formset(queryset=qs)